# Using method from another function to create a unique dbQuery to perform a prepare statement

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm having some trouble with using a method from a different function. They are both in the same class, but I keep getting the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in / / blabla.php on line 42"

The code I've written looks like this now:

```
public function connectDatabase() 
         {
         try {
             $DBC = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::dbhost.";dbname=".self::dbname."", self::dbuser, self::dbpass);
             $DBC->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );            
             }
             catch(Exception $e) 
             {
                 echo $e->getMessage();
             }
         }

public function InsertNewForumData( $data )
    {
         $new = $DBC->prepare( $data );
     $new->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because $DBC is undefined in your `InsertNewForumData` method. You can either pass it by reference by doing `self::InsertNewForumData( $data, $DBC );` and also add it to the parameter list of that method's declaration or else save it to `self::DBC` like this:

```
public function connectDatabase() 
         {
         try {
             self::DBC = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::dbhost.";dbname=".self::dbname."", self::dbuser, self::dbpass);
             self::DBC->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );            
             }
             catch(Exception $e) 
             {
                 echo $e->getMessage();
             }
         }

public function InsertNewForumData( $data )
    {
         $new = self::DBC->prepare( $data );
         $new->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using a singleton. I have updated my post to use self instead of $this

Comment: Oh, can't believe I missed that, hehe. Thanks a lot, Mike. Everything is working now.. :)